# Adding UIView to UICollectionviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a question about adding `UIView` in `UIcollectionviewcell`. I have`UIcollectionview` and is the condition, if condition is true I need to add `UIView` to `UIcollectionviewcell`. If the condition is false don't add. 
 After updating `UIcollectionview` `UIView` is added to `Cell` for which conditions is true and some for which the condition is false. How to add a `UIView` to `UIcollectionviewcell`? one, two or three `UIView` can be added cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
NSInteger dayStart = [self dayWeekStart:[self getCurentDate:indexPath.section]];

CalendarCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.item+1 < dayStart) {
    CalendarEmptyCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellemptyIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

} else {

    CalendarCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.item-dayStart+2];

    int todayDayRowInt = todayDayRow;
    int dayPlusShift = todayDayRowInt + dayStart - 2;

    cell.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];

    CALayer* layer = [cell layer];

    [layer setCornerRadius:15];

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z";

    cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    dateFromString1 = [NSDate date];

    dateFromString2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateFinish];

    dateFromString3 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateStart];


    if ([self checkDateFromCalendar:indexPath.section row:indexPath.item + 3 - dayStart] == 1) {

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [arrColor removeAllObjects];

        for (int i=0; i<appDelegate.selectPill.count; i++) {

            Pill *arrPill = [appDelegate.selectPill objectAtIndex:i];

            NSNumber *mDay = arrPill.manyday;

            int mDayInt = [mDay integerValue]+1;

            if ([[self sameDateByAddingMonths:[dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateStart] addMonths:indexPath.section addDay:indexPath.item + 3 - dayStart] compare:[self sameDateByAddingMonths:arrPill.start addMonths:0 addDay:mDayInt]] == NSOrderedAscending) {

                NSDate *verifiableDate = [self sameDateByAddingMonths:[dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateStart] addMonths:indexPath.section addDay:indexPath.item];
                NSDate *verifiableDate2 = [self sameDateByAddingMonths:[dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateStart] addMonths:indexPath.section addDay:indexPath.item+1];

                NSTimeInterval diff = [verifiableDate timeIntervalSinceDate:arrPill.start];
                NSTimeInterval diff2 = [verifiableDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:arrPill.start];

                yui = (diff2 - diff);

                NSInteger sss = diff / yui;

                if (diff >= 0) {

                    float fff = fmod (sss , ([arrPill.frequency doubleValue]+1));

                    if (fff == 0) {

                        NSArray *components = [arrPill.color componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
                        CGFloat r = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                        CGFloat g = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
                        CGFloat b = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
                        CGFloat a = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
                        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];

                        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0+(i*10), (i*10), 10, 10)];
                        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor color];

                        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    } else {

        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    }

    if ([dateFromString1 compare:dateFromString2] != NSOrderedDescending && [dateFromString1 compare:dateFromString3] != NSOrderedAscending) {

        if (indexPath.section == todayMonthSection && indexPath.item == dayPlusShift){

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0/255.0 green:162.0/255.0 blue:161.0/255.0 alpha:1];
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];

        } else {

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        }

    }

    return cell;
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your view visually to your 

 StoryBoard or Xib file and make custom cell classes make a connections

 Use below code snippet

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

PhotosCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 20.0)];
label.text = @"Hello";

[anotherView addSubview:label];

[cell.myView addSubview:anotherView];

if("Your condition is true")
{
      cell.myView.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
       cell.myView.hidden = YES;

}

return  cell;

}
```

Comment: It works if I need to add one uiview. But I need to add different amounts to different uiview cell. Some I do not need to add uiview.

Comment: @Alexey - i posted my new answer - once you have one UIView you can add subview of another view as well - that way you can add custom views for each cell

Comment: And what happens if the input parameters change? After reload UIColectionView.

Comment: @Alexey Can you describe what you want achieve - elaborate - parameters

Comment: I have uicollectionview and menu. I choose menu items and change of parameters for UICollectionview. When I create a cell I watch these parameters determine how to add uiview. If I choose a different item parameters changes. Next [self.collectionView reloadData];

Comment: @Alexey - post your code in Question - itself - then i can understand in better way

Answer (score 0):

Use the cell.contentView to get access to the cell's UIView.

**Example:**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyRootView *view = [[MyRootView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) someBusinessLogicParam:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
    return cell;
}
```

---

I think would help is you have a root view which takes in your business logic as parameters.  The business parameters will determine which views to display during the root view's initWithFrame.

Modified Example of MyRootView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame someBusinessLogicParam:(NSInteger)bp
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if (bp == 0) {
            UIView *yourChild1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            [self addSubview:yourChild1];
        } else if (bp == 1) {
            UIView *yourChild2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            [self addSubview:yourChild2];
        }else if (bp == 3) {
            UIView *yourChild3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            [self addSubview:yourChild3];
            UIView *yourChild4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            [self addSubview:yourChild4];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

You can then use the cell.contentView to add in the MyRootView along with your logic to what gets displayed.

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive about why it does not work?  Did you specify the "Cell" name in the Identifier in the story board?  Does your numberOfItemsInSection method return more than 0 items?  When you set a breakpoint In the YourView's initWithFrame, does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: This method add uiview to all cells. If you use it with the condition does not work.